# Designing Postgresql table with multiple foreign key candidates

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

When designing a table with 2 or more possible candidates for reference/foreignkey how should this be achieved?

Say we have the following:

```
Table Trigger {
...
- condition1  [FK: BookSales or BookPrice]
- operation1  [enum: and, or, not..]
- condition2  [FK: BookSales or BookPrice]
- operation2  [enum: and, or, not..]
- condition3  [FK: BookSales or BookPrice]
}
```

Now the the tables `BookSales`and `BookPrice`don't have exactly the same fields and should be reusable for different triggers.

**One idea** would be to create a table such as:

```
Table BookPriceOrSale {
...
- cType [enum: Price, Sales]
<fields for BookPrice>
<fields for BookSales>
}
```

And simply evaluating it based on `cType` with it as FK: `condition1  [FK: BookPriceOrSale]`.

**Another option** is of course creating an intermediary table that has the foreignkey for one and null for the other -- this however adds another table compared to the one above which eliminated one, but added additional columns.

```
Table TriggerCondition {
...
priceCondition [FK: BookPrice] 
SalesCondition [FK: SalesPrice] 
}
```

Here we instead reference it as `condition1  [FK: TriggerCondition]`

**A third option** I can imagine is using inheritance, but I am not too sure about this..

My immediate thoughts would suggest using option 2 for correctness, but I would like to know if someone more knowledgeable could lend some guidance as for how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use approach with a `Generic relations` feature
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: Could you add or describe the underlying structure of the implementation to your answer -- how it works in Postgre and possibly how to query it (non-ORM)?

Comment: On the DB side, it looks like two integer fields and one index.
The first field stores object type. 2nd object ID.
All other magic is done by Django in its metaclasses.  
The documentation on the link is extremely detailed. Try to use

Comment: Thank you Serge. Maybe I should just implement this myself and look the DB schema, but I think the answer would benefit immensely from an example query, maybe using the scenario detailed above.